# ViewPagerExtension example Android github

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to use viewpager Extension from android github https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions

I imported the example in eclipse and started getting many errors one if which is below.
for the `activity_fixed_icon_tabs.xml` layout.

The following classes could not be found:
- `com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.FixedTabsView`

Can someone please guide me to use this `ViewPagerExtension` in eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

ViewPagerExtensions is a library and need for run example project

right click on example project > prpoerties > android

then click add button and then select ViewPagerExtensions as library

clean and build your project